# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset

Tags: mysql, .net, .net-core, mysql-connector

Reading from the stream has failed.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I am getting this error specifically for a particular Stored procedure ( multiple queries and SP run successfully). Connection has default timeout of 30 sec, and the query takes not more than 5 sec to run. Strange thing is that if I rerun the query(by refreshing the application) I don't get the error, even if I try multiple times.

```
 using (MySqlConnection ms = new MySqlConnection(
    ConfigureData.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"]))
        {
            ms.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = ms;
                MySqlParameter c= new MySqlParameter("@cc", c);

                cmd.CommandText = "GetList";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(c);
                MySqlDataReader reader = (MySqlDataReader)await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                 {
                  // rest of the code
                  reader.Close();
                            
                }
            }
            ms.Close();
        }
```

Comment: how long your procedure take to execute from database. Also there may be issue with particular session. Also possible that there is something in uncommit stage.

Comment: @शेखर The procedure usually takes around 4-5 sec only, not more than that.

Comment: all of your code is async implementation? can you check without async version?

Comment: @शेखर This is a prod issue, I am not getting this in qa/dev . So will update once I get the opportunity.

Comment: @शेखर Having analyzed further, we found that it is the query that is taking more time to execute. However the query only takes more time (like 70 sec) to run for the first time but after that it takes less time (around 4-5 sec). Still trying to ponder what is happening on the SQL side.